# What's the correct way to include commas in Windows' day, month, year format strings?

Tags: winapi

MSDN says this about Windows' date format strings as returned by `LOCALE_SLONGDATE`:

> If spaces are used to separate the elements in the string, these spaces will appear in the same location in the output string. For example, to get the date string "Wed, Aug 31 94", the application uses the picture string "ddd',' MMM dd yy". The application uses single quotation marks to mark characters to display exactly as specified.

To me, this sounds like all characters *except* spaces must be escaped using single quotation marks. As shown above, the comma after `Wed` is escaped as `','` in the format string. However, when I query `LOCALE_SLONGDATE` using `GetLocaleInfo()` I get the following format string on my Windows system using the default locale (German):

```
dddd, d. MMMM yyyy
```

In contrast to the example on MSDN from above, there are no quotes around the comma here. It's completely unescaped, just like the space characters.

So, is that documentation on MSDN just very outdated (*cough* August 1994), or what is the correct way to format those date strings?

Comment: Microsoft's [`LOCALE_SLONGDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-slongdate) doc also provides `"dddd, dd' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy"` as another example, where clearly the comma is not escaped. Maybe it is related to [`LOCALE_SLIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-slist), without being explicit about it? Either way, I would say it is a deficiency of the documentation.

Comment: From experience you only need to escape characters that have meaning as date formatting codes (e.g. if you want a literal 'd' character, it needs to be escaped). Any characters that aren't a date formatting code are copied as-is.

Comment: There is some extra info here in remarks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformatex#remarks that say *"If the format parameter contains a bad format string, the function returns no errors, but just forms the best possible date string"* and other details, so it means you don't *have to* escape everything.

Comment: As [Day, Month, Year, and Era Format Pictures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/day--month--year--and-era-format-pictures) documents, *GetLocaleInfo* *could* return a *displayed* string. You can *SetLocaleInfo* and *GetLocaleInfo* to verify. Single quotation marks are necessary.